# How to "subtract" one character from another?

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to subtract two `Char` values? For example

```
'B' - 'A' = 1, 
'C' - 'A' = 2
```

Can some functions handle this?

Answer (score 5):

There's no universally defined notion of what *difference between characters* is (for instance, is `K` more similar to `k` than `l` is, or less?) so the safest thing might be to define the function yourself based on the requirements. You can guard-match on character ranges:

```
import Data.Char

charDist c d
 | isLower c, isLower d  = ...
 | isLower c, isUpper d  = ...
 | ...
```

Within each range, you can probably just use Unicode as the proxy space. The `Enum` class maps char values to ints, which can be subtracted in the obvious way:

```
charDist c d
 | isLower c, isLower d  = fromEnum c - fromEnum d
 | ...
```